# OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning:Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm

i tried to install sqldev tools in **ubuntu** and i got many problem even i have the **jdk java-17-openjdk-amd64**
also java is installed well
the error message showed in terminal :

```
Oracle SQL Developer
Copyright (c) 2005, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2393)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:755)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1953)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:384)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:228)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:170)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:311)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:281)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2398)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1392)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1390)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.initStatic(Toolkit.java:1427)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1401)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:624)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.LauncherUtil.verifyJdkVersion(LauncherUtil.java:173)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.LauncherUtil.checkLaunchPrerequisites(LauncherUtil.java:129)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.LauncherUtil.initialize(LauncherUtil.java:101)
    at oracle.ide.osgi.boot.OracleIdeLauncher.main(OracleIdeLauncher.java:80)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The options `-Xverify:none` and `-noverify` should not be needed and the fix is to remove them from the start configuration. If a software needs them to run, that software is broken and should be fixed. But the warning is entirely unrelated to the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` that prevents the application from running.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have to install and use the previous version of the java like JDK 11

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Comment: i tried to install it and i got this : sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
[sudo] password for miral: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-11-jdk is already the newest version (11.0.11+9-0ubuntu2~20.04).
openjdk-11-jdk set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.